# Getting a button to interact with an input to land in console

Tags: javascript, html

Using an html file i have created a  and  and I'm trying get the them to interact using a separate java script file.
I am using the console.log to check if my input is being received and pushed to the console by the button.

This is the body of the HTML file.

```js
const myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

function guess(myInput) {
  console.log(myInput);
}

myInput.addEventListener("click", document.getElementById("myInput"))
```

```html
<h1 id="random">Random Number guesser</h1>
<h2>Guess a number below between 1 - 100.</h2>
<div>
  <button id="button" onclick="guess()">Guess!</button>
  <input id="myInput" type="text">
</div>`your text`
<script src="config.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to bind an *`HTMLElement`* as the event-handler for the click event, on same HTMLElement? The event-handler should be the name of the function you want to call. Please, read the [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) documentation over at the Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: i was trying to get help from a tutorial as a potential solution which did not help, the idea was to pull the information when the on click event occurred, I am a novice coder so i am sure i have done a lot of wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fixing your guess function.
   On execution, your guess function does not accept any arguments. Lucky for us, we can access `myInput` in our JS file. Just by removing the myInput parameter from the `guess()` function, we can solve the problem. Which also renders the `eventListener` useless.

```js
const myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

function guess() {
  console.log(myInput.value); // use the value property to access the value of your input.
}
```

2. Your syntax for the `eventListener` is also wrong. The second argument of the `eventListener` is a callback function. Refer to the MDN docs for better explanation. Below is your code fixed to use the `eventListener` instead of the `guess()` function.

```html
<h1 id="random">Random Number guesser</h1>
<h2>Guess a number below between 1 - 100.</h2>
<div>
  <button id="button">Guess!</button>
  <input id="myInput" type="text">
</div>`your text`
<script src="config.js"></script>
```

```js
const myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
const myButton = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(myInput.value);
})
```

You don't need to use both `onclick` attribute and the `eventListener` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a goo starting point. When clicking the button the form will submit. The default behaviour is to reload the page -- you don't want that, therefore `e.preventDefault()`. Now you can get the value by the name of the input:

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.myInput.value);
});
```

```html
<h1 id="random">Random Number guesser</h1>
<h2>Guess a number below between 1 - 100.</h2>
<form name="form01">
  <button>Guess!</button>
  <input name="myInput" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i did not get your question what are you really trying to say but which i get that you trying to print the value of input box in console so here is the full page code

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Number Guesser</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="random">Random Number guesser</h1>
  <h2>Guess a number below between 1 - 100.</h2>
  <div>
    <button id="button">Guess!</button>
    <input id="myInput" type="text">
  </div>
  <script>
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  // Log the input to the console
  console.log("User input: " + userInput);
  // You can add your logic for processing the user input here
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```